# Lookup filters based on values populated from junction object's parents

Tags: lookup, data, lookup-filter, data-model

I have a junction object that connects a Lead to a Schedule object. This junction is called Schedule Registration.

A user creates a Schedule Registration by locating a Schedule they want to register a Lead to and then creating a Schedule Registration record via the Schedule's Schedule Registrations related list. When a user creates a Schedule Registration record this way, the Schedule record is pre-populated, and the user need to use the Lead lookup to search for a Lead.

I want a lookup filter to Lead that essentially says Lead.Type__c = Schedule__r.Type__c. Meaning the Type__c we have on the Lead should have the same value as the Type__c on the Schedule object. I know that because this is a lookup to the Lead, we can access Lead.Type__c through the lookup filter. However accessing the parent Schedule object is not available.

Using a formula field to pull the Type__c from Schedule to Schedule Registration won't work as we can't reference formula fields in a lookup filter. I tried making a quick action to create a Schedule Registration record from the Schedule record page, and then pre-populate a custom Type__c field on Schedule Registration, however it appears that pre-population doesn't happen until the record is saved, so that approach will not work.

I'm trying to avoid having to create a LWC or flow and wondering if there's anything simpler I can do. Of course one option is to have the user manually select a Type__c field on the Schedule Registration object before searching for a Lead, however that will be a last resort.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but it looks like we have to use Flow in such situations. Here is explained how:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8cONSAZ

Good luck!